# Update multiple records in table by using a reference table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update a table in SQL by using references from two other tables. I need `Table C` to be updated with the `ID` of records from `Table A` but only where a column from `Temp Table B` exists in `Table A`

**Table A**

| ID | ReferenceNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 321 |
| 3 | 213 |
| 4 | 413 |

**Temp Table B**

| ID | ExtractedNum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 213 |
| 2 | 413 |
| 3 | 321 |
| 4 | 123 |

Expected Results

**Table C**

| TableA_ID | TableB_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

I've tried a few different queries but none of them work the way I need it to:

```
UPDATE table_c 
  SET
      table_c.tablea_id = a.id -- int    
FROM table_a a
WHERE table_c.tableb_id =
(
    SELECT t.Id, 
           t.ExtractedNum
    FROM #tempTableB t, 
         table_a a2  
    WHERE t.ExtractedNum = a2.ReferenceNumber
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE c
SET c.tablea_id=a.id
FROM tableC c INNER JOIN
tableA a ON a.id=c.tablea_id INNER JOIN
#tempTableB b ON b.ExtractedNum=a.ReferenceNumber
```