# SQL query not executing on all records in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, left-join

I have a SQL query that is supposed to update a table with records that are found in a second table. Currently, I have a temp table that it's supposed to search through and for every matching record, `UPDATE` the main table but the query only executed on 4 matching records when it's supposed to execute on all 23 matching records.

Is there perhaps an issue with my query? If I use an `INNER JOIN` or `JOIN`, I get the result

```
(4 rows affected)
```

If I use a `LEFT JOIN`, I get the error message:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 87
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ChangeRequestId', table 'dbo.NSTest_RVCR'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Below is the `UPDATE` query I'm running

```
UPDATE c
SET c.ChangeRequestId = a.Id
FROM NSTest_RVCR c
JOIN dbo.NSChangeRequests a ON a.Id = c.ChangeRequestId
JOIN #tempExtractedTPNumber b ON b.ExtractedTP = a.TPNumber
JOIN NSReportVtest d ON d.Id = c.ReportVersionId
```

EDIT:

If I use a `LEFT JOIN` with `ISNULL()` as seen in the below query, I get the result: *(1025 rows affected)* but it still only updates the exact same 4 records.

```
UPDATE c
SET c.ChangeRequestId = ISNULL(a.Id,0)
FROM NSTest_RVCR c
LEFT JOIN dbo.NSChangeRequests a ON a.Id = c.ChangeRequestId
LEFT JOIN #tempExtractedTPNumber b ON b.ExtractedTP = a.TPNumber
LEFT JOIN NSReportVtest d ON d.Id = c.ReportVersionId
```

Original question where I had my initial issue can be found here: [Update multiple records in table by using a reference table SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662593/update-multiple-records-in-table-by-using-a-reference-table-sql-server/65662702#65662702)

Comment: column does not allow nulls. Alter table and allow null. If that's the case. Left join brings null values in some columns.

Comment: @Nissus Well I understand that but the issue is that the query doesn't execute on all records

Comment: Did you try "select c.ChangeRequestId,ISNULL(a.Id,0)"  instead of "update c set c.ChangeRequestId = ISNULL(a.Id,0)" to see differences in the results?

Comment: @Nissus Yes it only returns 4 records

Comment: It's only doing what you tell it. Only four records satisfy your join conditions. Perhaps you could post a reproduction (table creation, insert statements)

Comment: Learn to debug sql code. Change your update statement to a simple select, adding all the join columns and the PK columns to the select list. Examine the resultset and determine if the join logic is correct.